# Usage datetime on rdlc report

Tags: vba, rdlc

```
=Format(DateTime.Now(), "dd.MM.yyyy")
```

---> This result gives me ---> "01.06.2016"

I want to get a date of 6 months from now. I mean "01.12.2016"  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateAdd` [is the function you need](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/gg251759.aspx):

```
=Format(DateAdd("m", 6, Now), "dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Format(DateAdd("m", 6, Now), "dd.MM.yyyy")
```